# Force `unique` to treat NaNs as indistinct

Tags: matlab

I have a long matrix of numbers that represent molecular states. A subset might look like this:

```
 states = [...
  1     1     1     1
  1     1     1     1
  1     0     1     1
NaN     0   NaN   NaN
  1     0     1     0
  1     0     1     1
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
  1     0     1     1
NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
  1     1     0     0
 ];
```

where the `NaN` values are for states where the representation is unknown. In practice, this list might have hundreds of thousands of values. If I use the `unique` command to get the unique states, the result looks like

```
K>>unique(states,'rows')

ans = 

     1     0     1     0
     1     0     1     1
     1     1     0     0
     1     1     1     1
   NaN     0   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

because "unique treats NaN values as distinct".

How can I massage this output such that NaN values are not distinct? So that `[NaN NaN NaN NaN]` is distinct from `[NaN 0 NaN NaN]` but `[NaN NaN NaN NaN] == [NaN NaN NaN NaN]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
%// Get unique rows with in-built "unique" that considers NaN as distinct
unq1 = unique(states,'rows');

%// Detect nans
unq1_nans = isnan(unq1);

%// Find nan equalities across rows
unq1_nans_roweq = bsxfun(@plus,unq1_nans,permute(unq1_nans,[3 2 1]))==2;

%// Find non-nan equalities across rows
unq1_nonans_roweq = bsxfun(@eq,unq1,permute(unq1,[3 2 1]));

%// Find "universal" (nan or non-nan) equalities across rows
unq1_univ_roweq = unq1_nans_roweq | unq1_nonans_roweq;

%// Remove non-unique rows except the first non-unique match as with 
%// the default functionality of MATLAB's in-built unique function
out = unq1(~any(triu(squeeze(sum(unq1_univ_roweq,2)==size(states,2)),1),1),:);
```

---

**Example #1**

Input -

```
states =
    3.0000    1.0000    7.0000    8.0000
    8.0000         0    1.0000    6.0000
       Inf         0       NaN       NaN
    5.0000         0    1.0000         0
       Inf         0       NaN       NaN
    7.0000         0    5.0000    1.0000
       NaN       NaN   11.2000       Inf
       NaN       NaN   15.0000       NaN
       NaN       NaN   11.2000       Inf
```

Intermediate result using MATLAB's in-built `unique` + `'rows'` -

```
unq1 =
    3.0000    1.0000    7.0000    8.0000
    5.0000         0    1.0000         0
    7.0000         0    5.0000    1.0000
    8.0000         0    1.0000    6.0000
       Inf         0       NaN       NaN
       Inf         0       NaN       NaN
       NaN       NaN   11.2000       Inf
       NaN       NaN   11.2000       Inf
       NaN       NaN   15.0000       NaN
```

Notice that two rows with identical values - `[Inf 0 NaN NaN]` are still showing up and similarly we have another identical pair - `[NaN NaN 11.2000 Inf]`. We need to keep one unique row for each of these two pairs. Let's see how our code performs -

```
out =
    3.0000    1.0000    7.0000    8.0000
    5.0000         0    1.0000         0
    7.0000         0    5.0000    1.0000
    8.0000         0    1.0000    6.0000
       Inf         0       NaN       NaN
       NaN       NaN   11.2000       Inf
       NaN       NaN   15.0000       NaN
```

It worked alright!

**Example #2**

For the final test, let's test it out for cases when we have big numbers too in the input array like this one -

```
states =
            3            1            7            8
            8            0            1            6
          Inf            0          NaN          NaN
            5            0            1            0
          Inf            0          NaN          NaN
            7            0            5            1
          NaN          NaN       1e+100          Inf
          NaN          NaN           15          NaN
          NaN          NaN       1e+100          Inf
```

The intermediate result with `unique` + `'rows'` would be -

```
unq1 =
            3            1            7            8
            5            0            1            0
            7            0            5            1
            8            0            1            6
          Inf            0          NaN          NaN
          Inf            0          NaN          NaN
          NaN          NaN           15          NaN
          NaN          NaN       1e+100          Inf
          NaN          NaN       1e+100          Inf
```

So, our code must remove one of the final two rows.

```
out =
            3            1            7            8
            5            0            1            0
            7            0            5            1
            8            0            1            6
          Inf            0          NaN          NaN
          NaN          NaN           15          NaN
          NaN          NaN       1e+100          Inf
```

It does!

Comment: I like it. I'll take a look at it when I get to work in the morning.

Comment: I especially like your method of finding equal NaN values in the third line. It just saved me in another part of my code.

Comment: @craigim Good to know that it's finding use in other problems too! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial (and unsatisfying) answer that works for this particular instance but isn't general:

```
states(isnan(states)) = inf;
uniqueStates = unique(states,'rows');
uniqueStates(~isfinite(uniqueStates)) = nan;
```

Apparently MATLAB does not treat `Inf` values as distinct. I don't plan on having any `Inf` values in my application, but I can certainly imagine a scenario where there were both `Inf` and `NaN` values, in which case this would muddle them up.

**Actual Answer:**

So @Louis Mendo deleted his comment that led me to the final answer, but this seems to be robust:

```
function C = nanUnique(varargin)

A = varargin{1};
dummyVal = ceil(max(A(isfinite(A(:))))) + 1;
A(isnan(A)) = dummyVal;
C = unique(A,varargin{2:end});
C(C==dummyVal) = nan;
```

In a nutshell, find the largest value (that isn't infinity). That value rounded up + 1 is an integer (no floating point errors) and guaranteed to be unique. Replace all `NaN` by the dummy value, run `unique`, then put the `NaN` back where they belong.

Comment: Guaranteed, as long as x is not too large. Otherwise the nearest numbers (that can be represented on a 64 bit float) for x+1 and x might be the same.

Comment: As seb commented, seems like it won't work when you have big numbers too there, as in Ex #2 from this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25519756/3293881)

Comment: That will be true of the `unique` function itself as well. I dug into the internals of it and it first sorts the vector or matrix, performs a `diff` on it, then picks out the non-zero entries. So there is the potential from there as well.

Comment: The issue isn't with `unique`, but if you have `1e100` as max number of the array, then `dummyVal` would still end up as `1e100`. To verify, check the output from this - `1e100==1e100+1`. There's nothing `unique` can do about it.

Comment: I changed it from `+1` to `*2`, but the criticism stands. Much better to just deal with the `NaN` as they are.

Answer (score 1):

The other solution suggested is simpler.
But you could consider subclassing `double` type.
You would need to over-ride the `==` operator by creating your own [`eq()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-operators-for-your-class.html) method, that should use [`isequaln()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/isequaln.html) (NaN values are considered to be equal).
Anyway, something to consider.

Comment: I haven't worked with classes, so this may be a bit out of my league to try. However, `==` and `eq()` both work element-wise producing a logical array the same size as the original array, while `isequaln()` operates on an entire matrix, returning a single valued true or false if both argument matrices are the same size and have the same elements (ignoring `NaN`).